# how to find element button in div using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, findelement

I have three <div class= emploBox "> and each has a button. Buttons do not have unique names. How can I find this particular button?
I want to use class=cutTooLongTest and test 'automated tester' but I don't know how.
wants to find the button marked in yellow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDktc.png)

I have no idea for a solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need to find the XPath for the button using the text 'automated tester'.

The XPath expression should be like this:

```
//h2[text() = 'automated tester']//..//button[contains(@class, 'standard Button--icon')]
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class = 'cutTooLongTest' and text() = 'automated tester']/following-sibling::div/button[1]"));
```